# Django Social Auth not redirecting to next url?

Tags: python, django, facebook-login, django-socialauth

So I want to redirect after login to the same page. But Django Social Auth isn't redirecting.
It redirects to `"/pins/#_=_`

Html:

```
<a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.get_full_path }}">Facebook Login</a>
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^$', 'pinry.core.views.home', name='home')
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if 'next' in request.GET:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['next'])
        else:    
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/pins'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core:concept'))
```

Settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL          = '/login-form/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/login-error/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/pins/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL = '/new-association-redirect-url/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_REDIRECT_URL = '/account-disconnected-redirect-url/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_BACKEND_ERROR_URL = '/new-error-url/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
    "social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends",
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
    "django.core.context_processors.csrf"
    )
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue as yours I solved it by changing my login button URL from

`<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}>`

to

`<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}>`

Comment: what is `request.GET.next ` in that case?

Comment: @kn3l the `request.GET.next` will be whatever you have set for `next` in query parameters.
Eg: `www.example.com?next=/home/`
so the next will be `/home`

Comment: In my case `?next={{ request.path }}` worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

change `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/pins/'` to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`, or whatever u want to redirect
this propety tells where to redirect after login

Comment: Added my urls.py and views.py. How can I pass the next parameter in GET request after login by DSA? Presently it's not there hence its redirecting to "/pins"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What he wants do is if the user is redirected to login page from some other page like pictures/nature, he wants the user to go to that particular page picutres/nature.